# Copy files under modified name

Tags: find, rename, cp

I have to find all files in a directory ending by number (this part is OK) and copy them under a modified name (I don't know how to do this part).
Typically:

```
find $folder -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*-[0-9]\.jpg'
```

copy all those files to the same directory, naming them `$originalName-mini.jpg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`find`** + **`bash`** solution:

```
find $folder -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*-[0-9].jpg" -exec \
bash -c 'cp "$1" "${1:0:-4}-mini.jpg"' _ {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need `find` here since you're just looking in a single directory, just a shell loop will do the job. You also do not need to escape the dot in a filename globbing pattern.

```
for pathname in "$folder"/*-[0-9].jpg; do
    [ -f "$pathname" ] && cp "$pathname" "${pathname%-[0-9].jpg}-mini.jpg"
done
```

The parameter substitution `${variable%pattern}` removes `pattern` from the end of the value of `variable`.

The `-f` test makes absolutely sure that we're dealing with a regular file (or a symbolic link to one) and not a misnamed directory.

---

Using `find` to do the same:

```
find "$folder" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*-[0-9].jpg' -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        cp "$pathname" "${pathname%-[0-9].jpg}-mini.jpg"
    done' sh {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to append following command to your script.
Assume that you have the original name in `$originalName`, you ca use

```
cp $originalName $(basename $originalName .jpg)-mini.jpg
```

Comment: Can you please include the full script/command into your answer, it's a bit hard to understand how `cp` should be combined with `find` here.